# Perform raster calculated in R based on names

Tags: r, raster

I am working with rasters in R. I have a list of rasters from ten locations, and for each location I do have the raster data over ten years (2000-2010). The names look like that: "Raster2000_1"... "Raster2000_10" .. "Raster2001_1" ... "Raster2010_10". I want to calculate changes for each location (1-10) over time (2000-2010), ia. "Raster2000_2"-"Raster2000_1". How do I do this, based on the raster names only?

I was not able to add the years or locations as a new variable to each raster in my list. I tried:

```
raster_list <- lapply(raster_list, mutate(Year = unique(gsub("Raster(\\d{4})", "\\1", names(raster_list)))))
raster_list <- lapply(raster_list, mutate(Village = unique(gsub("^.*_(\\d+)$", "\\1", names(raster_list)))))
```

Thanks a lot!